# Lead and Lag function in Mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have two columns `case_id` and `assigned_date` in my ***temporary*** table in mysql. As there is no direct function to get lead and lag likewise oracle in mysql. Want to get lead and lag both values for assigned date against each case id generated . How to achieve that. Attached is my sample data.

```
case_id                                  assigned_date
41c19f76-e52e-c4c9-62c2-573c71ec5d50    2016-05-18 14:08:14.0
41c19f76-e52e-c4c9-62c2-573c71ec5d51    2016-05-18 14:25:22.0
41c19f76-e52e-c4c9-62c2-573c71ec5d50    2016-05-18 14:26:01.0
41c19f76-e52e-c4c9-62c2-573c71ec5d50    2016-05-19 07:19:13.0
41c19f76-e52e-c4c9-62c2-573c71ec5d50    2016-05-19 07:53:09.0
41c19f76-e52e-c4c9-62c2-573c71ec5d51    2016-05-19 08:18:01.0
41c19f76-e52e-c4c9-62c2-573c71ec5d50    2016-05-19 12:12:35.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *correlated* subqueries:

```
SELECT t1.case_id, t1.assigned_date,
       (SELECT t2.assigned_date
       FROM mytable AS t2
       WHERE t2.case_id = t1.case_id AND
             t2.assigned_date > t1.assigned_date
       ORDER BY t2.assigned_date LIMIT 1) AS next_date,
       (SELECT t2.assigned_date
       FROM mytable AS t2
       WHERE t2.case_id = t1.case_id AND
             t2.assigned_date < t1.assigned_date
       ORDER BY t2.assigned_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS prev_date
FROM mytable AS t1
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Forgot to mention my table is a temporary table and its giving me an error Can't reopen table.